# Error when creating geo lat/long properties with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I just started researching the use of `NEO4J` in a proof of concept so this may be just a newbie question:

It seems like I can't create a string property with a decimal point in cypher.
I am using `Neo4j 2.0.0-M03` and the cypher code is:

```
CREATE (n:Location { id: "102", geo_lat: "34.058349609375", geo_long: "-118.244186401367", lang: "en", title: "Los Angeles" } );
```

The response is:

```
==> Unrecognized option '1'
```

Am I doing something wrong or is a string with a point not a string in `neo4j/java`?

Comment: Where are you working with this cypher statement? I was able to successfully execute it against console.neo4j.org

Comment: Yup, seems to be an error somewhere else, works fine with http://console-test.neo4j.org/r/goq0e8

Comment: Update: the problem is actually the minus sign. I am using the Neo4jShell on Windows 7. The error occurs in both from the CMD window and the webadmin console. For now I will just leave geo properties out for my test imports and when I move to a dev server import again. Its good to know it works fine on Linux, thanks